# How to upload csv file into new database table with python and sqlalchemy

Tags: pandas, csv, sqlalchemy

! pip install mysqlclient

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Step 1: Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
path = "baby_names_2021.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
print(df.shape)  # To check the shape of the DataFrame

# Step 2: Create a connection to the database
username = "username"
password = "piece_of_pork"
hostname = "ssss.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com"
databasename = "database"

# Create the database engine
engine = create_engine(f'mysql://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{databasename}')

# Step 3: Upload the DataFrame to the SQL table
df.to_sql('baby_data', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

Comment: do you have `_mysql` variable defined anywhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. How can I check?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with `mysqlclient` installation. Check if you have an [available wheel](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#files) for your OS and your python version especially for [Windows](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/#description). Maybe you have to build the library from source.

Check the [FAQ](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/FAQ.html#importerror) of `MySQLdb`:

```
ImportError: No module named _mysql  # (or NameError?)
```

> If you see this, it’s likely you did some wrong when installing MySQLdb; re-read (or read) README. _mysql is the low-level C module that interfaces with the MySQL client library.

**Edit**:

In your installation directory (e.g. `venv/lib/python-<version>/site-packages/MySQLdb`), check if you have a file like:

```
_mysql.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  # Linux / Python 3.9
# OR
_mysql.pypy39-pp73-win_amd64.pyd  # Windows / Python 3.9
```